# How to train an underfitting model in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to train an LSTM in Keras but it seems to be underfitting.

```py
adam = Adam(learning_rate=0.1, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(124, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(62))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam)
history = model.fit(
              trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=431, validation_data=(testX, testY), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

My data represents a series of data breaches where the first 0 - 7 columns are types of companies and columns 0 - 51 are USA states as onehot vectors. My objective is to predict the next breach according to this dataset.

```
      date     size    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    0    1  ...   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49   50   51
0        1    32000  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1        2     3500  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2        3  1400000  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3        4   120000  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4        5    59000  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

The time taken on each epoch is 0s and the loss on the test data essentially remain the same. Here are the last 10 epochs of my model.

```
Epoch 90/100
 - 0s - loss: 130445623221660.6562 - val_loss: 5098486354074.1934
Epoch 91/100
 - 0s - loss: 130445622565865.9375 - val_loss: 5098486346506.8730
Epoch 92/100
 - 0s - loss: 130445622191126.0625 - val_loss: 5098485465787.7988
Epoch 93/100
 - 0s - loss: 130445621816386.2344 - val_loss: 5098484149524.7568
Epoch 94/100
 - 0s - loss: 130445621347961.4219 - val_loss: 5098484141613.4668
Epoch 95/100
 - 0s - loss: 130445620785851.6406 - val_loss: 5098483698846.1465
Epoch 96/100
 - 0s - loss: 130445620317426.8281 - val_loss: 5098483255046.9189
Epoch 97/100
 - 0s - loss: 130445619942686.9844 - val_loss: 5098482810903.7217
Epoch 98/100
 - 0s - loss: 130445619380577.2188 - val_loss: 5098481494640.6797
Epoch 99/100
 - 0s - loss: 130445619005837.3750 - val_loss: 5098481050841.4521
Epoch 100/100
 - 0s - loss: 130445618724782.5000 - val_loss: 5098480170466.3477
```

This is the graph showing the loss during the training and testing.
[image]
**After normalization**
Data:

```
      date          size    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    0    1  ...   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49   50   51
0        1  1.066633e-05  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1        2  1.166333e-06  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2        3  4.666663e-04  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3        4  3.999967e-05  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4        5  1.966633e-05  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Output:

```
Epoch 90/100
 - 0s - loss: 1425.8638 - val_loss: 8939.7717
Epoch 91/100
 - 0s - loss: 1397.5078 - val_loss: 8847.1606
Epoch 92/100
 - 0s - loss: 1403.1658 - val_loss: 8756.0660
Epoch 93/100
 - 0s - loss: 1453.6541 - val_loss: 9025.9873
Epoch 94/100
 - 0s - loss: 1435.4252 - val_loss: 8928.1981
Epoch 95/100
 - 0s - loss: 1414.3660 - val_loss: 8830.8435
Epoch 96/100
 - 0s - loss: 1391.6843 - val_loss: 8734.7518
Epoch 97/100
 - 0s - loss: 1365.5961 - val_loss: 8655.9235
Epoch 98/100
 - 0s - loss: 1431.5669 - val_loss: 8896.3086
Epoch 99/100
 - 0s - loss: 1409.6963 - val_loss: 9031.4488
Epoch 100/100
 - 0s - loss: 1466.6886 - val_loss: 9088.9677
```

Loss:
[image]

Comment: Your model is not underfitting, it just not learn anything at all. What are your data ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @ThibaultBacqueyrisses I have added an explanation for the data in the question. Is there any reason for the model not learning?

Comment: There is essentially no learning i.e a _no-fit_ condition. You have to specify your data in detail and the type of problem (classification, regression, something else) with the appropriate loss function

Comment: @hash_ir How much detail do I have to go in? The Date and Size columns are integers representing how many days have elapsed and how many records have been breached. The two onehot vectors are briefly explained in the question. The loss function is Mean Squared Error.

Comment: Is `size` the target data? You should strongly consider normalizing it.

Comment: Your data is sparse and just represents one-hot vectors for states and companies. What I understood from your problem is you are trying to predict one of 51 states for a given type of company. This makes your _X: type of company_ and _y: one or more states_ First, mse has no role to play here since you are classifying one or more states. Second, as far as I can see, your only raw features are the types of companies (one-hot). Why are you using an LSTM? Is there a sequence in the input?

Comment: @hash_ir I was planning to make a forecast for each of the features. Why would the size not represent a feature? The data shows that these breaches are occurring more frequently over time, from what I understood that would  be  the sequence.